# Microphone making noise, no recordings

Tags: sound, microphone

My microphone plugged in correctly but in recording it's just making noise.

https://www.sendspace.com/file/g7si02

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.